# What do the dotted lines represent in the hexagonal lattice system?

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, terminology, symmetry, dihedral-groups

[image]

The above is one of the four two-dimensional lattice systems. See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice#In_2_dimensions) for some info.

The parallelogram is the primitive unit cell, because it can be translated in order to recreate the entire lattice. So, what is the hexagon then? The conventional unit cell, whatever that means? Is it shown because the symmetry operations that can be performed spans a greater part of the lattice than that which is provided by the primitive unit cell?

Comment: I'm guessing it is to represent the fact that this unit parallelogram actually spans a hexagon (by rotating it arround the center by 120 degrees), hence the name of the lattice